# Proving the inequality problem

Tags: inequality

Proving the inequality:
$\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{a^2+b^2+c^2}>\frac{a+b+c}{3}$

$a, b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers

I know that it is the same as proving:
$a^3+b^3+c^3+abc>\frac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{2}$

However, I'm stuck in this step, I don't know how to prove it. Can someone help me with this problem?

Is it a problem where I need to apply the Chebyshev's inequality?

Comment: Is there any constraint on a,b,c?

Comment: Also, please change the title to make it less generic and more specific to your problem. Best is just to state the question in the title...

Comment: For $a, b, c  \geq 0,  a^3 + b^3 \geq a^2b+ab^2 $

Comment: If $a = b = c = 1$ it fails. Maybe you mean $\geq$.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to showing that for $a,b,c > 0$,

$$\begin{aligned} 3(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) &\geq (a + b + c)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) \\
&= a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + ab^2 + ba^2 + bc^2 + cb^2 + ac^2 + ca^2\\ ab^2 + ba^2 + bc^2 + cb^2 + ac^2 + ca^2 &\leq 2a^3 + 2b^3 + 2c^3. \end{aligned}$$

Since $a^3 + b^3 - a^2b - ab^2 = (a-b)^2(a+b) \geq 0$ since $a,b > 0$, then we have (by using a similar argument for $b,c$ and $c,a$) $$\begin{aligned} ab^2 + ba^2 &\leq a^3 + b^3 \\ bc^2  + cb^2 &\leq b^2 + c^2 \\  ac^2 + ca^2 &\leq a^2 + c^2.\end{aligned}$$

The required inequality follows.

---

Alternatively, define the discrete random variable $X$ that takes value $a,b,$ and $c$ with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ each respectively. Let $E(X) = \mu > 0$ (since $a,b,$ and $c$ are $> 0$). By Jensen's inequality, we have
$$E(X^3) \geq E(X^2)^{1.5} = E(X^2)(E(X^2))^{0.5} = E(X^2)(E(X)^2 + Var(X))^{0.5} \geq E(X^2)E(X)$$
since $E(X^2) = E(X)^2 + Var(X)$, $Var(X) \geq 0$, and $t \mapsto t^{1.5}$ for $t > 0$ is a convex function.

Thus,
$$E(X^3) = \frac{a^3 + b^3 + c^3}{3} \geq \frac{a + b + c}{3}\frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{3} = E(X)E(X^2). $$
The required inequality follows.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, required to prove $$0\le 3(a^3+b^3+c^3)-(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)=$$ $$=2(a^3+b^3+c^3)-(\,a^2(b+c)+a(b^2+c^2)+(bc^2+b^2c)\,)= ^{def}F(a,b,c).$$

WLOG $a=\max (a,b,c).$

Differentiating $F$ with respect to $a,$ keeping $b,c$ constant, we have $$\frac {\partial F}{\partial a}=6a^2-2ab-2ac-b^2-c^2=$$ $$=(a^2-b^2)+(a^2-c^2)+2a((a-b)+(a-c))\ge 0.$$ Therefore $F(a,b,c)\ge F(b,b,c).$ So we have $$F(a,b,c)\ge F(b,b,c)=2b^3+2c^3-2b^2c-2bc^2=$$ $$=2(b+c)(b^2+c^2-bc)-2(b+c)(bc)=$$ $$=2(b+c)(b^2+c^2-2bc)=$$ $$2(b+c)(b-c)^2\ge 0.$$